# Is there a proper name for this graph/model?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-modeling, descriptive-statistics

Is there a proper name for this graph/model?

[image: Graph/Model]

Comment: welcome to MSE. What exactly are you talking about as a graph/model? Are you referring to the psychological (?) model (i.e. something to do with gender expression)? Or are you looking for something to do with the fact that it's triangle shaped abstractly? Do you mean it's some kind of flowchart, and you want to know if that has a mathematical name? As it stands it's entirely unclear what you're asking, but we might be able to help you if you clarify

Comment: I'm talking about the triangle shaped flowchart. I've been reading many research studies and I've seen the flowchart to represent its statistics/findings multiple times. Is there a name for it? (The numbers are correlation coefficients representing the relationship between the bubbles)

Comment: Not that I know of, but maybe somebody knows. I'm tagging this descriptive-statistics because that tag might have people who have seen this before.